# PayPal Express Checkout shipping options integration

Tags: paypal, e-commerce, checkout

I'm integrating [PayPal Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/) into our e-commerce platform.

Our existing non-PayPal checkout has a pretty standard 4 step flow:

`1. Cart -> 2. Shipping Address -> 3. Shipping Option -> 4. Payment`

> NOTE: Our checkout flow is very similar to Shopify checkout in case you're familiar with that.

I'm trying to understand where in the checkout flow PayPal Checkout can fit in, in particular how we ensure the customer is able to choose an appropriate shipping option (e.g. next day vs standard vs international etc.) once they've selected their shipping address.

Shopify currently offers PayPal Checkout both on step 1 (Cart) and step 4 (Payment).

Adding PayPal Checkout to step 4 (Payment) seems pretty straight forward because we can use the shipping address captured in step 2 (Shipping Address) and pass [`shipping_preference: 'SET_PROVIDED_ADDRESS'`](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-order_application_context) when creating the PayPal Order, preventing the customer from changing their shipping address in PayPal Checkout -- this is critical as it ensures customers are unable to invalidate their shipping option by, for example, changing from a UK -> US shipping address.

However, if we wanted to add it to step 1 (Cart) or even directly on product pages (which Shopify also offers), I can't see how it would work as there doesn't appear to be a way to offer up shipping options after a customer chooses / changes their shipping address *within the PayPal Checkout*?

Comment: I tested PayPal Express Checkout from step 1 (Cart) on Shopify and it turns out you approve the price of just the product amount in the PayPal window and you're subsequently redirected to step 3 (Shipping Option) on Shopify's checkout to choose your shipping option -- this means the customer approves the amount without shipping but is then charged the price including shipping -- I'm surprised it's possible to capture more than was approved?!